# Storing array as value in arb files

Tags: flutter, localization

Is there any way to store arrays as values in any arb file while using app localization in flutter?
Here is an example of what I aim to do -

```
"inviteTitle": ["Span 1 ", "Span 2", "Span 3"],
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Transform you list, for example "inviteTitle": "Span 1:Span 2:Span 3".
2. String _inviteTitle= AppLocalizations.of(context)!.inviteTitle;
3. List spans= _inviteTitle.split(':');

Answer (score -1):

you can use **flutter_localizations** plugin

[reference link medium](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/localization-multi-language-in-flutter-5cedb6ff459b)

create folder and file and save them

```
{
  "english_language": "English Language",
  "hello_world": "Hello World"
}
```

**For Example:**

app_en.arb, app_es.arb, app_id.arb, app_it.arb

Comment: My use case involves using text spans and instead of using separate key-value pairs for each text span in the arb file, is there a way I can keep all text span values in one key in an array?